# Sharing (characters) is Caring!

Tags: code-challenge, number, arithmetic, number-theory, rosetta-stone

## Overview

Consider the following task:

> Given a positive integer **n > 0**, output its integer square root. The integer square root of a number **n** is the largest value of **x** where **x<sup>2</sup> ≤ n**, usually expressed with the formula `floor(sqrt(n))`.
>
> Examples: `25 -> 5`, `24 -> 4`, `40 -> 6`, `1 -> 1`.

This task is easy enough on its own. However, in this challenge, your task is to solve this in *as many languages as possible* using a set of only *25 characters.*

## Example

First, you need to pick a *set* (no duplicates) of 25 bytes. It may look something like this (note the leading space):

```
 ()*-.05:=>Mabdhilmnqrst|
```

Your challenge is then to, using only characters in this set, construct a solution to the problem in as many *text based* (sorry, Piet) languages as possible. You can use characters as many times as necessary, but you must not use characters outside the set.

The solutions can be either *full programs* or *functions*, but not snippets. For example, using this set of characters, I could do:

```js
M -> (int) Math.sqrt(M)    // Java (lambda expression)
M => Math.sqrt(M)|0        // Javascript (unnamed function)
lambda M: int(M**.5)       // Python (lambda function)
```

As I've used 3 languages, this would give me a score of **3**.

Please also include the set of bytes you are using in your answer.

### Rules

- This is a [rosetta-stone](/questions/tagged/rosetta-stone) challenge - your score is the number of languages your submission includes. The highest score wins. Standard loopholes apply.
- For this challenge, a 'language' counts as a distinctly different programming language - multiple versions of the same language (Python 2, Python 3, etc) are banned.
- Programs only need to work for inputs within the language's standard integer range.
- Programs with the exact same source code (polyglots) are not allowed.
- To be more specific, it is a set of *bytes*, not characters - so you can use the 05AB1E `£` and the Jelly `ɱ` as the same character (because they have the same codepoint).

Please don't feel as though you have to beat all other solutions - if you have an interesting answer, post it!

Comment: Can our solution be in Piet if we have the code be the raw ppm? (e.g. `P3 10 10 255 `...)

Comment: We need another pixel based language so we can have polyglots with poor old piet

Comment: Can we count a polyglot of A and B as language A if we provide another solution that only works in B?

Comment: Could you clarify "distinctly different"? For example, is [Numberwang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Numberwang_(brainfuck_derivative))--using digits instead of `[]<>.,+-`-- distinctly different from Brainfuck? What about [SNUSP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/SNUSP), a 2D Brainfuck derivative? For both of them, the resulting code would not work in Brainfuck.

Comment: @WheatWizard you can't have two programs that are exactly the same, but if you modify one to be different then it's allowed. And yes, if you really must, you can use the raw ppm as "text" for Piet  :P

Comment: @JungHwanMin the second is definitely distinctly different as it's 2D. I'd also say numberwang is sufficiently different as it has a different character set.

Comment: @JungHwan generally, a different language is a different creator, different syntax , etc. However with esoteric languages the line gets blurry. Trivial, "1 new command" modifications of brainfuck aren't really different to bf, but larger derivatives like the 2D one you linked encourages different ways of programming and so counts as a different language.

Comment: C, 23 Bytes `f(x){return pow(x,.5);}` and 20 characters used `f(x){retun powx,.5;}`

Comment: @WadeTyler Not sure why you've commented that, but you should know that you've counted `x` twice in your character set. Also, if you name the function something like `p` that's already in the set then you don't have to count `f`.

Comment: @FlipTack I wanted to make it as a post, for others who didn't use C in theirs because of reasons, and talked with someone that it would be a better idea to leave is a comment on your post so others can see it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## 20 languages

Using  `()-#*.05;=>^Vefikloqrst` (24 characters) so far:

```
let f l=floor(l**0.5);;       OCaml
let f l=floor(l**0.5)         F#
f(l)=floor(l^.5)              Julia
f(o)=floor(o^.5)              PARI/GP
s^+>5 0>5 0*.5l               Pyth
(* **.5).floor                Perl 6
floor.(**0.5)                 Haskell
flr.(tt ^.5)                  Wonder
l=>l**.5^0                    JavaScript
l->l**.5^0                    Cheddar
.5^5*5f                       Pyke
(isqrt)                       Maple
ri.5#i                        CJam
isqrt                         Common Lisp
0.5^k                         MATL
*.5^0                         Jelly
*.^0                          M
t0^                           05AB1E
q f                           Japt
r#                            Pushy
V-                            gs2
```

Comment: Try adding `flr.(tt ^.5)` for Wonder (no added chars).

Comment: If you would like to add `{}[]`  you can add Brain-Flak.  [Here's the program](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#TU3BEcAwCFoHFmiHyTkJ5@wpmqSXhx4g4IQSIAcYLKDiFokNrPms1BbbmcqokGkhR8ddFNSKtn8tMqoe7XRVePiDqyrr3Ot8m/N9Pg)

Comment: If you added `~`, you could do `sqrt~~` in [Stacked](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/stacked/stacked.html); it takes input from the TOS and leaves output on the stack.

Comment: julia also has `isqrt`

Comment: `isqrt` in Julia wouldn't count because polyglots are not allowed.

Comment: The Pyth one would be shorter and more readable if you used `ttt5` instead of `+>5 0>5 0`.

Comment: C, 23 Bytes f(x){return pow(x,.5);} and 20 characters used f(x){retun powx,.5;} You can replace the curly brackets with round brackets.

Comment: Congrats on winning, enjoy the bounty! ^_^

Answer (score 8):

## 10 languages

Character set of 19 characters (in **CP-1252**):

```
,-/12@QUVX^fkmt¬÷␊␍
```

Where `␊` represents a *line feed* and the `␍` represents a *carriage return*.

([Script for checking the characters](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@19TVqludWih4eEVhzccnu1Ve3iVi4KCUmhxaopCckZiUWJySWpRsZWC@uH96ko6XArIIB2o0Cc1L70kw0rh8H4lnf//vVJzciqtQHKPJvQ@mtDFZWDq6GToChIpMYzQjeNyDzaygmgO0@Xyys9Jg/By00K5vBILSiC8Q2vSuHwdQ3wgvIi4bK6AyuxUCE/HMA3IA9kIAvoOgUYlRlz@icWZxWARQ6ClRvq5hoe3cxkVJyblpMKsjojQ1Y0DAA))

#### Jelly, 2 bytes

```
Æ½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@47dDe////G5kAAA)

#### 05AB1E, 2 bytes

```
t1X-^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@19iGKEb9/@/kQkA)

#### GS2, 2 bytes

```
V-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/gs2#@x@m@/@/kQkA)

#### Jolf, 3 bytes

```
mfU
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=bWZV&input=MjQKCjI1) (works best on Firefox)

#### Japt, 2 bytes

```
¬f
```

[Try it here!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=rGY=&input=MjQ=)

#### MATL, 3 bytes

```
X^k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x8Rl/3/v5EJAA)

#### Pyke, 3 bytes

```
,1f
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%2C1f&input=24)

#### Pyth, 6 bytes

```
/@Q2t2
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2F%40Q2t2&input=24&debug=0)

#### Oasis, 6 bytes

```
1␊2/m1÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/oasis#@2/IZaSfa3h4@////41MAA)

#### 2sable, 9 bytes

```
t1X-XX--^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/2sable#@19iGKEbEaGrG/f/v5EJAA)

Comment: `cU` also works in Jolf.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Although it's shorter, it would mean to add `c` to the list of characters. He's already using both `m` (in the Oasis sub-answer) and `f` (in the Japt and Pyke sub-answers).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen ik, it's just for posterity

Answer (score 6):

## 5 languages

Gonna add more languages soon.

#### Character set (22 bytes):

```
s^Q.5=>*|0√Lrdmlab :/1
```

#### Pyth

```
s^Q.5
```

#### Javascript

```
Q=>Q**.5|0
```

#### Actually

```
√L
```

#### CJam

```
rdmQ
```

#### Python

```
lambda Q:Q**.5//1
```

Comment: You can replace `|` by `^` in your JavaScript answer to save a byte in your character set.

Answer (score 6):

## 5 languages

```
[].,+<>{}()0134879
```

18 characters.

I'm trying not to use any alphabet characters...

**[Brainfuck](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#7ZmxDcQwDAMHUvBVSoKLGNp/DEeW3/gHMgKpKnB5oEkqntcYjJ6BEB2G9iSHOIE/BcA0EEwA8qJgAJlXco84jgFYFOUUrQp7RHtEyGMoDtxGQWtiwch2iYLRZNaZeLkqGGEI8hX7lIjv9VgfzlJ5y0wHRwsBCTcqytukY0LeEL1od4OGreAXD44G7aldEt0QXJQKw/7ZwL1qn1cbkzl3JfmRD9G0KF6imPO@Hw), [Brainfuck++](http://www.jitunleashed.com/bf/index.html), [Brainfuck-ng](https://github.com/elboza/brainfuck-ng/), [Braintrust](https://gist.github.com/Sgeo/fe54715fc61d1d98f4cc), ...**

```
,[[>++++++[<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++<]>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<+>]<<<[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+<<]],]>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++[<<<<<[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+>+<<]>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<+>]<<+[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<<+>>>>+<<]>>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<<+>>]<<<<[>>[<+>>>+<<+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]<[>+<+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]<+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]>>>>>>>>+<<<<[>>>+<<[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]<<]>>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+<]<[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<+>]<+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]>>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]<<<<<<+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<++++++++++>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++[<+<<]<[+[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+<]<+<<]>>>>>]<<<[<++++++[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++<]>.[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]]++++++[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++<]>.
```

Doesn't work for over `224` because `256` (= (sqrt(225)+1)^2) overflows.

Replaced all `-`s with `+`s to use one less character. (e.g. `-` -> 255 `+`s)

*Original Program*

```
,[[>++++++[<-------->-]>[->++++++++++<]>[-<+>]<<<[->>+<<]],]>>>>>>>-[<<<<<[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]<<+[-<<+>>>>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<<<<[>>[<+>>>+<<-]<[>+<-]<-]>>>>>>>>+<<<<[>>>+<<[->+>[-]<<]>>[->+<]<[-<+>]<-<-]>[-]>>>-]<<<<<<-<++++++++++>[-<-[<+<<]<[+[->+<]<+<<]>>>>>]<<<[<++++++[->++++++++<]>.[-]]++++++[->++++++++<]>.
```

**[Brain-Flak](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#TU3BDQAxCFoH/t2mcRLj7D2wvaYPDSDgQhZATjBokOYSiQOk6ZyVR2xnZYVDokaKzrcomDva/r3IcD3aqarQ8IKnqnzu9X9ba4wP)**

```
({}(())[()])(()){{}((({})({}((({}())))[{}{({})({}[()])}{}]))[({}[{}])])([({}(())[()])]){(({}()({}[(({}[(())]()){(([({}{})]{}))}{})]{}))[({}[{}])])}{}{}}{}{}({}[()])
```

@WheatWizard's code. Thanks for the permission!

**[Brain-Flueue](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Brain-Flueue)**

```
({}())(())(())({}){{}({})({}<(({})<({({})({}[()])}{})>())>)([{}]<({})>({}))({}<‌​({}<([({})]){()<({}())>}{}(<()>){({}[()])([{}]())}{}>)>)({}<({})>)({})({})}{}({}[‌​()()]){}
```

Another @WheatWizard's code.

**[Numberwang](https://tio.run/nexus/numberwang#7ZnRDQMxDEJXAtWSz/sPljpOo1bqCOCvUz6fCODLeiJQM8ESHZT2JEKcwI8CaBosJEl5UaDIzCdxRhxHkBZFO8Wowh4xHlHyGJoDjlHAmtgwclyiYQyZfSZerhpGGYJ8xb4l4nM99oezVN4y08ExQmDSjQryNumYkDdEL9rToGkr@MaDo0F7epfkNAQXpcZwfjbgrNr31cZk7l1JvORDNC2KP1GsFfEG)**

```
8440999999419999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999909999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999997049999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999990999999999917049999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999991907111499999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999900911778700000009999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999994111114999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999090911704999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999190711949999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999991190000911700499999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999911900711114004190009119999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999997140919999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999997199999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999970000000091111400091149999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999990904999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999711700499999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999909171499999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999919071999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999199999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999970499999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999970009999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999997111111999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999199999999990499999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999919999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999994191171494999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999091719117000007111419999994999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999099999999170349999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999997799999949999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999990999999991703
```

**[Spoon](https://web.archive.org/web/20140228003324/http://www.bluedust.dontexist.com/spoon)**

```
00101100010000100010111111001000110000000000000000000000000100000011010001000000101111111111011001101000100000011101000110110110110010000001001010110110011001100101100011010010010010010010010000001000110110110110110010000001010101011011001101000100000011101000110110111001000000110111010010010010101101100110100100010000001101110100100011011011011011001000100100010001110100100101011011000001101100100010101100000110110000011010010010010010010010010101101101101100100010010010101101100100000010101000100000001101101100110100100010000001010110011011001000000111010001101100001100000110100010000000110100100100000011011011011011011011000011111111111101000100000011000001000111011011001101100100100100000010101100110111011011001101001001001001000110110110110010001111111100100000010111111110110011010001010001000000011001111111100100000010111111110110011010001010
```

[Per meta consensus,](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11055/60043) this code should be okay, even though no interpreters are currently available.

Answer (score 4):

## 5 languages

Using `()*/12 dlinpqrstu` and newline (18 characters) so far.

#### Common Lisp

```
isqrt
```

A built-in function.

#### QBasic

```
input q
print int(sqr(q))
```

#### Python 3

```
print(int(int(input())**(1/2)))
```

Python 3 used for floating-point division without decimal points.

#### Pip

```
q**/2//1
```

Unnecessarily golfy to show off the unary inversion operator `/`. Takes input from stdin. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@1@opaVvpK9v@P@/iREA)

#### [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp)

```
(d sqrt (q((n nsqr input) (i (l input nsqr) (s n 1) (sqrt (s n (s 1 2)) (s 2 (s (s (s 1 n) n) nsqr)) input)))))
(q((input)(sqrt 1 1 input)))
```

`sqrt` is a helper function whose arguments are: the current guess `n`, `n` squared, and the `input` number. If `input` is less than `nsqr`, we've gone too far, so return `n` minus 1; otherwise, recurse, adding 1 to `n` and adding `n + n + 1` to `nsqr`. (The math is a bit complicated because tinylisp only has subtraction built in.) The second line defines our actual function, which takes a single `input` and returns the result of `sqrt` with `n` starting at 1.

Comment: If you would like to add `{}[]`  you can add Brain-Flak.  [Here's the program](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#TU3BEcAwCFoHFmiHyTkJ5@wpmqSXhx4g4IQSIAcYLKDiFokNrPms1BbbmcqokGkhR8ddFNSKtn8tMqoe7XRVePiDqyrr3Ot8m/N9Pg)

Answer (score 3):

## 6 languages

Using `retun flosq(agm1)\,i` and extended codepoints `B1` and `BC` for 22 bytes so far.

**GameMaker Language**

```
return floor(sqrt(argument1))
```

**Pyke**

```
,1f
```

**Julia**

```
isqrt
```

**Maple**

```
(isqrt)
```

**Stuck**

```
i\
```

**TI-Basic (hex dump)**

```
B1 BC 72
```

Note that 0x72 is `r` in ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

## 7 languages

`24` chars:

```
limQi->(nt)Mah.sqr_ ?;:\
```

#### [CJam](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CJam)

```
limQ
li       e#Read Int
  mQ     e#Integer square root
```

#### [Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/)

```
i->(int)Math.sqrt(i)
```

#### [Chaincode](https://code.sololearn.com/cAw9mAl5Q9AX/?ref=app)

```
q_
q  #sQuare root
 _ #floor
```

#### [Math++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B)

```
_sqrt ?
```

#### [Grin](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Grin)

```
;q:
```

#### [Stuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Stuck)

```
i\)
```

#### [Unilinear](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unilinear)

```
iMivMiMs
i            Read input
 Mi          Convert to int
    v        Square root
    Mi       Convert to int
      Ms     Convert to String
```

#### R

```
sqrt
```

### Costs too much bytes

#### [Python](https://www.python.org/)

```
lambda i:int(i**.5)
```

Comment: Can add `R`: `sqrt`